# NSData to NSUrl and viceversa

Tags: ios

I am using multipeer connectivity to send files. When I send it I have it in form of NSData, but the method requires NSUrl, and the same when the file is received. The device receives the NSUrl and I have to convert it to NSData. So:

NSdata => NSUrl ........ NSUrl => NSData

For the first (NSData to NSUrl) I have tried this:

1)

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sendData.xxxxxxx"];

    [myData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *urlData = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSProgress *progress = [session sendResourceAtURL:urlData withName:@"Resource" toPeer:peerID withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

2)

```
NSURL* fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] init];
    [myData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
```

Finally I can send the url:

```
[session sendResourceAtURL:urlData withName:@"Resource" toPeer:peerID withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

For the second I do:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

...but sometimes the app crashes, and this happens when I try to send larger files. I think this is because the system takes time to writetofile, and anyway the whole process will take longer if I need to 'save' the file again. Is there a faster and more secure way??

Comment: What debugging have you done on the crash - where is it occurring in the code etc ?

Comment: it says the localUrl is nil

Comment: if you are doing conversions between types, you should put NSAssert(BOOL condition, string to printout); and make sure that the contents successfully converted. You can test hits by seeing if the content is nil aka NSAssert(localUrl != nil, @"localUrl should not be nil, localUrl failed to create from string");